# Quero acessar uma função PHP a partir do Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Minha duvida é da URL do ajax, quero saber como faço para acessar a função da minha classe

Ajax com jQuery

```
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: "Usuario.php?apagar",
        data: {titulo: 'Ola mundo'},
        success: function( data ){
            $('#ajax').text(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Houve algum erro no ajax');
        }
    });
```

PHP

```
class usuario extends geral
{
    function apagar(){
         echo $_POST['titulo'];
    }
}
```

Não faço idéia de como fica o URL no Ajax.

Comment: Nao cara, esses tópicos que voces estao marcando nao estao me ajudando :/